# How to configure Varnish to conditionally ignore cookie based on Vary response header?

Tags: cookies, varnish, esi, vary

I'm using Varnish 3 for caching responses from a web application that uses Edge Side Includes (ESI).

There are generally two types of responses from ESI endpoints:

- some are authentication-specific, responses thus use `Vary: Cookie, Accept-Encoding`
- some be cached for all users regardless of cookies, thus responding with `Vary: Accept-Encoding` (without varying by cookie)

All requests do contain a `Cookie` header with various cookies. Requests with no `Cookie` header are responded to with `Set-Cookie`. Note that this is not the case of `__`-prefixed cookies from e.g. Google Analytics - these are cookies set by a legacy application, and I have no means to change this behavior.

**Is there a way* to configure Varnish 3 to remember that responses from respective ESI endpoints do not vary by cookie, thus future requests should ignore the `Cookie` header altogether and use a cached response instead of fetching a new one from the backend?**

(*) other than hardcoding URIs into Varnish config, i.e. I'm looking for a way for Varnish to respect cookie-less `Vary` header for requests that *do* contain cookies.